# Dispatching SOAP function calls

Tags: java, soap

I'm receiving a certain string value over the network and I need to call a function based on that value.

So this is more or less what I have at the moment:

```
String methodName = soapObj.getMethodName();

switch(methodName) {
    case "getTemperature":
        getDeviceTemp();
        break;
    case "getBrightness":
        getScreenBrightness();
        break;
    ...
}
```

And.. there are about 60 to 70 methods supported like that.

What's the most elegant way of handling above situation without using reflection? (The app is moderately constrained performance-wise).

Comment: Do you mind me asking for more details about your use case or the domain? Just curious to know more about the situation.

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith Communication with a device known as Direct Digital Control that runs on embedded linux. (Building Management Solution, controlling lights, electricity, water valves etc).

Comment: Why are you getting the device temperature, screen brightness, etc., but not returning it?

Comment: My impression is that SOAP is not a lightweight, high-performance protocol to begin with. Reflection might not be such a bad choice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest to:

- Define an interface with a method that will be called inside every `case`, e.g.

  ```
  public interface ServiceMethod {
      public void execute();
  }
  ```
- Create a map that will contain contain instances of `ServiceMethod` findable by the a `String` key, e.g.:

  ```
  Map<String, ServiceMethod> serviceMethodMap = new HashMap<>();
  ```
- Fill up the `serviceMethodMap` map with `ServiceMethod` instances (this is to avoid the `switch`), e.g.:

  ```
  serviceMethodMap.put("getTemperature", new ServiceMethod() {
      public void execute() {
          getDeviceTemp();
      });
  serviceMethodMap.put("getBrightness", new ServiceMethod() {
      public void execute() {
          getBrightness();
      });
  ```
- Finally replace the `switch` with:

  ```
  final ServiceMethod serviceMethod = serviceMethodMap.get(methodName);
  if(serviceMethod != null) {
      serviceMethod.execute();
  }
  ```

---

Update 2/18/2015, added Java 8 support

- Define an interface with a method that will be called inside every `case`, e.g.

  ```
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface ServiceMethod {
      public void execute();
  }
  ```
- Create a map that will contain contain instances of `ServiceMethod` findable by the a `String` key, e.g.:

  ```
  Map<String, ServiceMethod> serviceMethodMap = new HashMap<>();
  ```
- Fill up the `serviceMethodMap` map with `ServiceMethod` instances (this is to avoid the `switch`), e.g.:

  ```
  serviceMethodMap.put("getTemperature", () -> getDeviceTemp());
  serviceMethodMap.put("getBrightness", () -> getBrightness());
  ```
- Finally replace the `switch` with:

  ```
  final ServiceMethod serviceMethod = serviceMethodMap.get(methodName);
  if(serviceMethod != null) {
      serviceMethod.execute();
  }
  ```

Comment: Uh, there is `java.util.concurrent.Executor`... Naming your interface like a JDK-provided class is not a very good idea ;)

Comment: @fge Good spot, renamed.

Comment: You can also use `Runnable`.

Comment: @tcb Yes, you are right, I have suggested a new interface to allow having a different return type then `void` and allowing to have arguments passed to the `execute` method.

Comment: or use reflection?

Comment: @user1737909 Yes, it is possible, however not recommended, because: 1) compile time rather runtime checks 2) worse performance

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I've read many answers regarding passing a func as a param using reflection or invocation but this is clearest and most concise.

Comment: @Amalgovinus with Java 8 and lambdas it is even simpler, updated the answer

Comment: How do we pass parameters and set return type

Comment: just what I was looking for with java8, thanks a ton!

Comment: I do not see what the advantage is of using this approach to the approach with the ugly `switch-case`, could you explain this further? Because this seems longer and more complex, altough different versions of this solution are mentioned everywhere when it comes to removing `switch-cases`.

Comment: @hamena314 you can look up "open closed principle"

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to create an interface for your function, for instance:

```
public interface ParameterGetter
{
    int getValue()
}
```

Then have a `Map<String, ParameterGetter>` in which you would pair keys with implementations of `ParameterGetter`. If no entry exists, of course, the method call is wrong.

While this is easy, however, it is not practical. Many frameworks, including light ones, include annotation systems which will do the job automatically for you -- you should try and find one, and use it.

There is also another solution -- since this is JDK 7 you are using, you'll have it: [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

It also requires that you implement an interface, but using this, you can load your method implementations easily. This is what I use in one of my projects, and it works quite well; the only trouble with it is you need to create a file in `META-INF/services`, but it's a trouble you only have to do once for each method you create; or if you use Maven, there is a plugin to generate it for you.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Can you give me an example of a framework that does such job for me in Java?

Comment: The "lightest" one I know of is [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections), but I would be surprised if there didn't exist something even lighter. Using reflections require that you write some code to handle that... But as you seem to be doing SOAP (which I have never done), there probably exists much better solutions

Comment: BTW, an example of such a standardized framework (but not SOAP dedicated) is JAX-RS, an implementation of which is Jersey

Comment: There is another solution too, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (**I know the drawbacks**) but there is trade of, rename all your methods to exact same as the service would return String and execute the method with 2 lines of code.

```
Method m = Class.forName(MyClass.class.getName()).getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
m.invoke(null);
```